# In/for a scientific paper

Tags: prepositions

Which of in/for should be used in a context like this:

> A document may be published by more than one publisher. For example, in/for a scientific paper, each of the authors can be considered a publisher of the paper.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. Semantically the word "for" seems correct, however it has some problems in this sentence.

- "for example for" is repeating the same word too often (even though that does not constitute a grammatical error).
- "for" is very much an everyday word. In sentences about scientific papers, one often tries to use roundabout intellectual words and phrases.

Here are some alternatives then:

> - For example, with scientific papers each of the authors can be considered a publisher of the paper.
> - For example, this includes scientific papers where each of the authors can be considered a publisher of the paper.

Comment: What about "about"? , about a scientific paper, each of ...

Comment: @Shayan , "about" does not exactly fit this situation. Other ideas are "regarding scientific papers" or "in terms of scientific papers", however those would fit better when there's a contradiction, like "However, in terms of scientific papers..." In this case though, there is not a contradiction.